# If $\frac{AM}{MB}=\frac{m}{n},$ then $AM=\frac{m}{m+n}AB$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

If $\dfrac{AM}{MB}=\dfrac{m}{n},$ then why $AM=\dfrac{m}{m+n}AB?$

I am trying to show that if $M$ lies on $AB$ and $AM:MB=m:n$, then $$\vec{OM}=\dfrac{n\vec{OA}+m\vec{OB}}{m+n}.$$ For that problem I am supposed to notice $$AM=\dfrac{m}{m+n}$$ but I don't see it.

Comment: notice that MB=AB-AM then replace MB with that in AM/MB = m/n then solve for AM in terms of AB

Comment: Add $1$ to both sides

Comment: @MathLover, I actually tried that. If we add $1$ we get $$\dfrac{AM+MB}{MB}=\dfrac{m+n}{n} \\ \dfrac{AB}{MB}=\dfrac{m+n}{n}$$ This isn't what I need.

Comment: First write as $MB / AM = ...$ and then add $1$.